# How to enable css suggestions in django-html file in vscode?

Tags: html, css, django, visual-studio-code

Similar hints are available in `html` files

[image: hints form html files]

I want to get them in `django-html` as well. Is there any way to enable them?

I installed the following extension for vs code and enabled emmet support in django-html

https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Django Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=almahdi.code-django) extension